# iAd in published app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store, iad

I have released an app. It's already on the AppStore. I integrated advertisements provided from Apple.I want to ask you when do my ads start to show up in my app? Because I downloaded it and the ads are not in it yet.

Comment: Did you enable ads on the App profile, and test them while devving?

Comment: and… where are you from? iAd is not available in all countries

Comment: I am from romania.how should I enable ads in my app profile?...all I did was that I implemented iAd programmatically and when I tested it on simulator and my device the test ads provided from apple shown up.thats all I did.what should I do more?help me please because my app is already on store but the ads didn't show up.

Comment: in iTunes Connect check the iAd section, at your app.. check "Ad Status”.. you must have “Live ads”. Romania is supported from 28 Oct 2014 - I’m from Romania to, I have never saw an iAd (there are not yet any ad with country Romania yet). To check… you must make a VPN or Proxy with an external IP (US, UK, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened to me. I contacted the support team, and they answered that they have a problem and wanted me to re-upload the binary. If you are sure to configure everything such as bank, tax account etc, then you can try to re-upload the binary.